# Passing a list to a function that returns a dictionary, how to only get the value and not the key

Tags: python, python-3.x

So for example:

```
def myfunc(function):
    return {
          "key1": "hello" + function
      }

mylist = ["key2", "key1"]

print(myfunc(mylist[0]))
```

When I print this out it gives me both the key, and the value of the function. But I just need the value. How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I added an answer, but which solution you should go for depends on what you truly are trying to do

Comment: Can you turn this into an actual running example? It should be just a few more lines. Include what exactly you want the result to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return just the value

```
def myfunc(function):
    return "hello" + function

mylist = ["key2", "key1"]
print(myfunc(mylist[0]))
```

Output:

```
hellokey2
```

If you don't want to change the function, then access the value of the dictionary

```
def myfunc(function):
    return {
        "key1": "hello" + function
    }

mylist = ["key2", "key1"]
print(myfunc(mylist[0])['key1'])
```

Output

```
hellokey2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use also use the .get method :

```
def myfunc(function):
    return {
          "key1": "hello" + function
      }

mylist = ["key2", "key1"]


d = myfunc(mylist[0]).get("key1")
print(d) 
#hellokey2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this.

```
def myfunc(function):
    return {
          "key1": "hello" + function
      }

mylist = ["key2", "key1"]

print(myfunc(mylist[0]).values()[0])
```